# How to set data context of ViewModela View's xaml?

Tags: c#, listview, design-patterns, mvvm, win-universal-app

I'm trying to set the data context of a View to the list contained in it's ViewModel. But when I've tested the current set up, it seems the `data context` between the ViewModel and View is set incorrectly.

To debug this issue I set up a message box in the constructor of my View, and I get the following error message, which hints at the data context not being set correctly: "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*"

The list is also used in another ViewModel which shows that the list is not empty, which hints further at a data context issue.

Does anyone know what the flaw is in setting up the data context between the View and ViewModel?

This is the ViewModel containing the list:

```
namespace LC_Points.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewSubjectGradeViewModel 
    {


        public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel()
        {

            AddedSubjectGradePairs = new ObservableCollection<ScoreModel>();

        }


        public ObservableCollection<ScoreModel> AddedSubjectGradePairs { get; set; }       

    }
}
```

And this is the View and View code behind:

```
<Page x:Class="LC_Points.View.ViewSubjectGradePage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:LC_Points.View"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:vms="using:LC_Points.ViewModel"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{Binding ViewSubjectGradeViewModelProperty1}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">



    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--  Title Panel  -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Margin="0,12,0,0"
                       Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                       Text="LC POINTS" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5"
                       CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"
                       Foreground="DarkGreen"
                       Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
                       Text="View Grades" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--  TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid  -->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="19,9.5,19,0">

            <ListBox Height="400"
                     Margin="0,0,0,-329"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding AddedSubjectGradePairs}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Subject}" /><Run Text=" - " /><Run Text="{Binding Points}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

View code behind:

```
namespace LC_Points.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ViewSubjectGradePage : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();


        public ViewSubjectGradePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(DataContext.GetType().ToString());
            messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="NavigationHelper"/> associated with this <see cref="Page"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the view model for this <see cref="Page"/>.
        /// This can be changed to a strongly typed view model.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }



        private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region NavigationHelper registration


        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Try showing the dialog in `OnNavigatedTo` or equivalent event. Not on the constructor.

Comment: Here's a -1 for a snapshot of an exception.  Never EVER do this in a question.  Look at that dialog--at the bottom it says "Copy exception detail to the clipboard".  You click **that link**, then paste it into an [edit].  A picture of an exception is worse than useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to delete any generated code from your View's code behind that the template provides that you aren't using. This can cause confusion because the template wants you to use a local ObservableCollection as your DataContext.

There are 3 main ways of setting up a ViewModel to the DataContext of a View.

1. Use the code behind of the View:

   ```
   public ViewSubjectGradePage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel();
   }
   ```
2. Use XAML (other Page properties removed for easier reading):

   ```
   <Page x:Class="LC_Points.View.ViewSubjectGradePage"
       xmlns:vms="using:LC_Points.ViewModel">
       <Page.DataContext>
           <vms:ViewSubjectGradeViewModel/>
       </Page.DataContext>
   </Page>
   ```
3. Use an MVVM framework like [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx). This will auto-wire your View and ViewModel based on standard naming conventions.

I prefer option 3 since it can provide a much more loosely coupled system, but may be overkill for a very small project plus there is a learning curve with any framework, but the benefits are great. Option 2 is my second vote since it keeps the code behind cleaner. Option 1 is something I don't do anymore, but is a nice quick way to get it working.

Comment: I've tried both the code behind and Xaml solutions you posted above, but with each approach the contents of the list are not displayed on the View's list view, just blank. This is the first approach http://hastebin.com/tadakeduko.cs and the second http://hastebin.com/gazeyuseku.xml   Any ideas what the issue could be or how I can debug this further? Thanks

Comment: The code on either of these look fine. Can you post the ViewModel code? Also, when you run the debugger, check the output window. It will output any binding errors. It can point you to a mis-named property and can be very helpful.

Comment: Looking at your sample code in the question, your ViewModel is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged so when your constructor sets your observable collection, the view is not getting notified.  I like to have private readonly fields for collections and have the actual property return the field. This way binding always works. If you change the entire collection like your constructor is doing, you have to emit the PropertyChanged event so the view knows to update.

Comment: So I tried the above suggestions, no binding errors in the output window. This is my updated View, VM and View code behind,  https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/842e56610473c9217acc still no change. Any idea how I could debug this further, shouldn't be that complicated I'm thinking. This is the repo on github so you can test this yourself if you have time https://github.com/BrianJVarley/LC_Points

Comment: I created a pull request for you that shows the issues. To summarize here, a common data store was needed. A new ViewModel was being correctly initialized and all the binding was correct, it was just creating a new collection every time rather than referencing a common data store. One ViewModel was storing data to a local variable so the next ViewModel knew nothing about this data.

Comment: Just merged the commit, binding working now. I've read your above explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be due to how you are assigning the `DataContext`. In your XAML, you are binding the DataContext to a property. I don't see anywhere in your code where you are actually assigning the data context to the `defaultViewModel` or the properties within it.

Try to update your constructor to the following.

```
    public ViewSubjectGradePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

        this.DataContext = this.DefaultViewModel;
    }
```

If you are wanting to assign it to a property within the `DefaultViewModel`, you may do so there as well. Then remove the DataContext assignment in your XAML.